# .NET Inheritance with Collections "Object Reference Not Set..." Errors

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, collections

I am constructing a collection of objects, and need to use inheritance on a base class - I have been trying for hours in various ways and can't get this to work whatsoever - the error is always "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The idea in the example below is that an object is instantiated, and within that lies a collection of Students when I try to access the `oDemo.Students(0).Name` property the error is raised. Otherwise the object appears to have instantiated OK.

Here is the code being used to instantiate and access the class (from ASP.NET).

```
Dim oDemo As New MyDemo.Students
lblTest.Text = oDemo.Student(0).Name
```

Here is the sample code from the class library:

```
Public Class Students
    Private p_Students As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Test)
    ReadOnly Property Student() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Test)
        Get
            Dim alTestNames As New ArrayList()
            alTestNames.Add("John")
            alTestNames.Add("Brian")
            alTestNames.Add("Scott")
            For iLoop As Integer = 0 To alTestNames.Count - 1
                p_Students.Add(New Test(alTestNames(iLoop).ToString))
            Next
            Return p_Students
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public MustInherit Class TestBase
    Private p_Name As String
    ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return p_Name
        End Get
    End Property
    Sub New(ByRef sName As String)
        p_Name = sName
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Test
    Inherits TestBase
    Sub New(ByRef sName As String)
        MyBase.New(sName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not sure if I am totally missing the point in some way - any help is gratefully received. If any more info/background is needed please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialized the p_Students field, it is Nothing and causes the exception.  Fix:

```
Private p_Students As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Test)
```

Note the *New* keyword.  That's the quick fix, a more sane approach would be:

```
Public Class Students
    Private p_Students As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Test)
    Public Sub New()
        p_Students = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Test)
        p_Students.Add(New Test("John"))
        '' etc..
    End Sub
    ReadOnly Property Student() As System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of Test)
        Get
            Return p_Students
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks - this has solved the problem - the example code was a massive help.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error message because you never initialise `p_Students` in the class `Students`. You also keep re-adding the same names to the p_Students array each time you access the `Student()` property. You might want to initialise the array and add the test names just once in a constructor.

Comment: I just corrected the issue with the arraylist always sticking the first entry in - but that makes no odds. Could you clarify what you mean about initialising p_students? Thanks for your help.